# Copy entire directory from docker container

Tags: docker, docker-container

Is it possible to copy an entire directory from a Docker image into a local directory? Normally when copying a file, I would do something like this:

```bash
docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target
```

I've attempted to do the following, which does not work:

```bash
docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container/* /host/path/target
```

Comment: What if you just give the folder name without `*`? According to Docker, the definition of `docker cp --help` - **Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem**

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne that did it thanks! Didn't like the wild card.

Comment: Your question has the wrong title. You want copy from "docker container" and not from "docker image".

Answer (score 1):

As per @PraveenPremaratne's answer, my problem was using the wild card `*` to try and copy all the files. Instead the source should just be the directory name itself:

```bash
docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container/srcDir /host/path/targetDir
```

Comment: Amazing! Allowed me to copy all SQL Server databases located on the data folder to the host with a command like this: `docker cp f777bdf4c4f91538726a777dc81a36b6ad1ad09f7770c31e0762b777380ee8e0:/var/opt/mssql/data /Users/leniel/Downloads/sqlserver_backup`